# C# How to add SOAP header like <ns:From><ns:Address>###</ns:Address></ns:From>

Tags: c#, soap, header

Trying to add header to

```
<ns:From><ns:Address>###</ns:Address></ns:From>
```

I'm using following code:

```
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)){
 var header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("ns:From", "", "<ns:Address>###</ns:Address>");
}
```

But I'm get `<ns:From>&lt;ns:Address&gt;###&lt;/ns:Address&gt;</ns:From>`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Find answer online.

```
public class FromHeader : MessageHeader    {     
    public override string Name => "ns:From";
    public override string Namespace => "";
    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {                       
        writer.WriteStartElement("ns:Address");
        writer.WriteString("###");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}


using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add( new FromHeader() );                
}
```